Reducing the off-diagonal elements of the matrix while maintaining its rank
While working on some problems in quantum information theory, I arrived at the following question:
I have an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $r$. Additionally, its diagonal has only $r$ non-zero elements. Is it possible to gradually (continuously) diminish the off-diagonal elements of $A$ while maintaining its rank $r$ at any stage? If yes, what is the procedure?
Evidently, when all the diagonal elements set to zero, the rank would be $r$, so it is fixed at the beginning and the end.
